# Stay on same page instead of 404 when using FileResult in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in controller:

```
public ActionResult Download(string file){
    ...
    ...

    if(System.IO.File.Exists(file)){
        return File(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), contentType, newFilename);
    }

    return ??;  //what should return here ?
}
```

If no file exists then stay on same page where that action was called. How to do that ?

If `return null` then will display a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by taking a look at this question [ActionResult return to page that called it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288806/actionresult-return-to-page-that-called-it). The first answer by [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9714/chuck) gives you all that you need:

```
return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: It give me error: Cannot convert expression `RedirectResult` to `FileResult`

Comment: @SnakeEyes is your method truly `ActionResult Download` or is it `FileResult Download`? The reason I ask is because `Redirect` produces a `RedirectResult` which implements `ActionResult`. `FileResult` also implements `ActionResult`. If you keep the method return type `ActionResult` you shouldn't be having that issue